# Não consigo pegar valor da tabela e usar no ajas

Tags: php, ajax, table

Fala galera, blz? Sou iniciante em php e tenho uma tabela populada com while e preciso usar o valor de uma td em uma select em outra página retornando em uma modal. 
A estrutura que montei funciona se colocar o valor manualmente no script, mas quando busco direto da tabela não vem informação nenhuma.

Quando eu troco de Data: {despesa: despesa}, para Data: {despesa: 4}, os dados vão corretamente pra Div na Modal, senão só aparecem os cabeçalhos.

O código está assim:

Index.html - TD

```
<td id="despesa"><?php echo $dados['cod_despesa']; ?></td>
<td id="janeiro" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#modal_detalhes"><?php echo $dados['janeiro']; ?></td>
```

Div - Modal

```
<div id="dados" class="modal-body modal-xs"></div>
```

Script

```
function janeiro(despesa)
        {
            var page = "analitico.php";
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: page,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
                        },
                        data: {despesa: despesa},
                        success: function (msg)
                        {
                            $("#dados").html(msg);
                        }
                    });
        }
        $('#janeiro').click(function () {
            janeiro($("#despesa").val())
        });
```

Analitico.php

```
$sql_detalhe_janeiro = "select..";  $detalhe_fevereiro = mssql_query($sql_detalhe_fevereiro);
```

Tabela modal

```
<?php 

    while($dados = mssql_fetch_assoc($detalhe_janeiro)) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dados['DESCRICAO']; ?></td>
```

Comment: O método `.val()` é para `<input>`. Testa usar `$("#despesa").text()`.

Comment: Fala Sergio, blz? Funcionou, está trazendo os dados da minha select mas só traz da primeira despesa da tabela, então não está enviando o array...
Procurei alguma coisa sobre isso aqui mas não achei nada que ajudasse a colocar o json em uma table. Pode me ajudar nisso? abs

Comment: Como assim? Você quer enviar toda a tabela para o arquivo analítico?

Comment: Não, vou enviar só o cod_despesa que vai ser usado em outra select no analitico.php ( ..where cod_despesa = $cod_despesa ). Na td onde está essa informação coloquei o id 'despesa'.

Answer (score 0):

E se você fizer assim?

```
<td id="despesa"><?php echo $dados['cod_despesa']; ?></td>
<td id="janeiro" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $dados['cod_despesa']; ?>" data-target="#modal_detalhes"><?php echo $dados['janeiro']; ?></td>
```

Retornar o seu analítico como *json*

```
$('#janeiro').on('click', function () {
    var id   =     $(this).data('id');

    var page = "analitico.php";
        $.ajax
                ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: page,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
                    },
                    data: {despesa: id},
                    success: function (msg)
                    {
                        $('#modal_detalhes').modal('show');
                    }
                });
});
```

Comment: Assim o cod_despesa não vai pra analitico.php. retorna um boolean(false) no var_dump.

Comment: você acrescentou o comando `data-id="<?php echo $dados['cod_despesa']; ?>"` na linha do mês ?